# Why aJqgrid[0].grid.headers[i].el.hidden≠aJqgrid.getGridParam('colModel')[i].hidden

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I get a visible table header？for example: I have 10 columns, after columnchooser (sort and hide) after 8 columns, how can I get the current table header information, I wrote getGridParam ('colModel'), these Object sets are not sorted.

Comment: Please include in all your questions the information about the **version** of jqGrid and the **fork** ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7), which you use (can use).

Comment: @Oleg I used jqgrid version is 4.7.0

Answer (score 0):

The `el` property (`aJqgrid[0].grid.headers[i].el` in your case) is [HTMLTableHeaderCellElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableHeaderCellElement) (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.14.0/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts#L20)). It's DOM element. Thus to test, whether the element is hidden, you can use the [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style) property:

```
 aJqgrid[0].grid.headers[i].el.style.display === "none"
```

or

```
$(aJqgrid[0].grid.headers[i].el).is(":hidden")
```

The value should be the same as the value of `hidden` property of `colModel`.

Comment: I would like to use aJqgrid [0].grid.headers [i].el to get columnchooser after colNames and colModels'Id, are there other ways? The purpose is to export these rows by the order, colNames for the EXCEL sheet head, colModels'Id used as select subquery

Comment: @ChaoZhang: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. Your question was **why** `aJqgrid[0].grid.headers[i].el.hidden` is not equal to `aJqgrid.getGridParam('colModel')[i].hidden`. My answer: `aJqgrid[0].grid.headers[i].el.hidden` is undefined and you have to use `aJqgrid[0].grid.headers[i].el.style.display === "none"` instead.

Comment: @ChaoZhang: If you want to get notification about changing the order of columns then you should use events or callbacks existing in jqGrid. The exact answer depand on **the version** and **the fork** of jqGrid, which you use (can use).

Comment: I want to get these colNames and colModel's name After function of columnchooser exec.
For a example, i defined colModel Array 
 `...colModel:[{name:'name',label:'nameCol'},
      {n‌​ame:'id',label:'idCo‌​l'},
      {name:'note',lab‌​el:'noteCol'}
      ]`
Aft‌​er $(tableSelector).jqGrid('columnChooser'),I hide 'note' column,and sort two columns left,can I get sortable colModel?  `[{name:'id',label:'idCol'},{name:'name',label:'name‌​Col'}]`

Comment: @ChaoZhang: Sorry, but I asked you 3 times about the version of jqGrid and the fork ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7), which you use. I wrote that my answer depends on the information. Why you don't answer me?

Comment: @ChaoZhang: If you use old jqGrid 4.7, then you should use `done` callback of the `columnChooser`. You will have to call `remapColumns` inside of your implementation of the done` callback: `done: function (perm) { if (perm) { this.jqGrid("remapColumns", perm, true); }}`. The `perm` array provides you the new order of the columns.